# how can i fix this error, XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: php, api, soap

I am trying to make SOAP API using PHP but getting this error please somebody help me out.

[Result of server.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFbVV.png)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question. Also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where is the code for `server.php `  The response image  is not only an improper way to post here, it is no help.